# Adding actions to firebase cloud messaging notification

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to add Actions (button bellows the notification) for a Web application.

I tried to add actions to firebase-messaging-sw.js, But nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add the actions to a notification created in onBackgroundMessage() callback.

Can you provide example code of what you've tried so far?